# DataBinding DataGrid to Custom Data Structure

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

So I am just joining the WPF club after dabbling in Winforms for a couple of years. I am definiately enjoing the databinding in WPF, but I am having trouble with the `DataGrid`.

I have a highly-customized data structure that stores results from a SQL query, which I would like to continue to use in WPF. I have seen examples of binding to lists of objects, but not for anything dynamic like a SQL query.

Is there some interface that I can make my data structure implement so the `DataGrid` can get the necessary information such as the row & column count, headers, and the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to bind to my custom structure similar to a `DataTable`, allowing the `DataGrid` to "discover" information about my structure.

The short answer is to implement the following interfaces:

`IList`
`IEnumerable`
`ITypedList`

As well as inheriting from `CustomTypeDescriptor` (or implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor`)

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834454/wpf-data-binding-example-of-custom-type-descriptor) helped a lot in dealing with the `CustomTypeDescriptor` stuff which was the most challenging.

My enumeration object was simple an object that stored a reference back to the main table so it could ask what the value was at a specific row and column.

```
public AgilityTableRow(AgilityTableBase table, int rowIndex)
    {
        _table = table;
        _rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }

    public object this[int columnIndex]
    {
        get 
        {
            return _table[columnIndex, _rowIndex]; 
        }
    }

    public object this[string columnName]
    {

        get 
        {
            return _table[_table.GetFieldIndex(columnName), _rowIndex]; 
        }
    }
```

Note: this class needs to implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and can simply forward the call to the table to get the properties:

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return _table.GetProperties();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the items should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you should put them in a ObservableCollection<>, so that the grid will be notified about changes.

if you set AutoGenerateColumns to true, then the Grid will automatically create a column for each property of your Model.

if you just have "raw" data and no Model-Class, then i think you have to create the columns manually. WPF bindings are very flexible, it is also possible to bind to indexed properties / arrays etc. Maybe this helps you with "dynamic" data.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myArray[0]}" />
```