# Filling a DataGrid with Dynamic Columns and Rows with Editing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to implement the "1st Approach" as documented at:
[Filling a Datagrid with dynamic Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452134/filling-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns)

I've modified the code to include 2 rows and added a User class. I've run into two problems: 1) the "fixed" columns don't display the data, and 2) if I try to edit the data in the DataGrid, the program aborts (under debug it indicates that I can't edit the data).

How do I get the "fixed" columns to display data and how do I make the columns editable?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var newColumnNames = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2" };

        //var users = new User[] { new User { Id = "First User" } };
        var users = new User[] { new User { Id = "First User", Image = "image 1" } ,
         new User { Id = "Second User", Image="image 2"}};

        var newProps = new Dictionary<string, object>[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Name1", "First Name of First User" },
                { "Name2", "Second Name of First User" },
            },
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Name1", "First Name of Second User" },
                {"Name2", "Second Name of Second User" }
            }
        };

        //Column Headers
        AddColumns(newColumnNames);

        PopulateRows(users, newProps);

    }
    void AddColumns(string[] newColumnNames)
    {
        foreach(string name in newColumnNames)
        {
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                // bind to a dictionary property
                Binding = new Binding("Custom[" + name + "]"),
                Header = name,
                IsReadOnly = false
            });
        }
    }
    void PopulateRows(User[] users, Dictionary<string, object>[] customProps)
    {
        var customUsers = users.Select((user, index) => new CustomUser
        {
            Custom = customProps[index]
        });
        grid.ItemsSource = customUsers;
    }
}
```

XAML File

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="409" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="782" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="id" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Image}" Header="image" IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Supporting code includes:

```
class CustomUser : User
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Custom { get; set; }
    public CustomUser() : base()
    {
        Custom = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've am using a dynamic DataGrid in one of my projects.

to add the columns i uses such a code:

```
Table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { 
                new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Surame", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("First Name", typeof(string)),

                });
```

the datasource of the Grid is the DataTable Table.

to add the dynamic Columns, i used a foreach loop for every item and just addet it with  that pattern:

```
foreach (entry in collection)
{
  Table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column header, typeof(entry type)));
}
```